# ios NSAssert analog for normal build?

Tags: ios, nsassert

It recently came to my attention that NSAssert only works in debug mode. Is there an analog that will work in normal builds?

Comment: Standard if/else logic coupled with a manually thrown NSException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Xcode automatically turns off assertions for release builds. If you really want to have them in your release build you can remove the `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1` flag from Other C / C++ flags in your build settings.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know you could do that!